# Threading a Tk GUI and a cpu intensive math equation

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I'm trying to use threading in combination with a Tk GUI, and thus far I've been having issues with the GUI freezing as the cpu intensive task seems to overload the GUI. I'm very new to threading and having a lot of problems trying to get both to work simultaneously.

So in the background, a cpu-intensive math equation is running, in the foreground, a GUI pops up that has a button that allows users to enter data into an array for later, I'd want both of there processes to be going simultaneously. Any suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import math

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.addWidgets()

    def addWidgets(self):
        self.wordEntry = Entry(self, width = 16)
        self.wordEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.wordEntry.insert(END, "Enter")

        self.addBtn = Button(self, text = "Add", width = 16, command = self.add)
        self.addBtn.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

    def add(self):
        global wordList
        wordList.append(self.wordEntry.get())
        print(wordList)

def startThreads():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=mathFUNC1, args = (100000,))
    t1.start()

def mathFUNC1():
    #This is what the math function would be essentially

def mathFUN2():
    #This would be called by mathFUNC1

def main():
    startThreads()
    app = App()
    app.wm_title("GUI")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So hopefully there is a way that would allow the math functions to run, but also allow the App class to not freeze and be used by the user in the foreground.

Comment: your code looks OK.  you need only `app.mainloop()`  and variable in `def  mathFUNC1(variable)`. And `wordList = []`.

Comment: It's not so much an issue of whether it runs or not (and I greatly simplified my real code to make it more digestable) its just that when I run it, the complexity of the mathFUNC1 and mathFUNC2 functions is so great it can cause the Tk to freeze for ~15 seconds at a time, and I was looking for a way to keep it from freezing.